# Esc para salir, Cualquier tecla para iniciar c++/c

Tags: c++, c

Recuerdo haber visto en un videotutorial aleatorio que el chico usaba en su codigo "Presione cualquier tecla para iniciar la ejecucion, Esc para salir" y usaba creo que algo con una etiqueta llamada getch o similar, Debo implementar eso en mi proyecto ya que ese es uno de los parametros,Alguien sabe como se hace? no paso del codigo primitivo de:

```
int main ()
{
printf("Oprima 1 para realizar la ejecucion, De lo contrario pulse cualquier 
tecla");
scanf("%d", &Opcion);

while(Opcion==1)
{ 
// una ejecucion cualquiera
printf("Desea ejecutar nuevamente?");
scanf("%d", &Opcion);
}

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

`printf("Presiona una tecla para continuar"); 
getch();`

creo que podría ser así :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion getch()

Comment: Hola @DanielPérez. Estás publicando muchas respuestas rápidas y veo que la mayoría de éstas está camino a ser eliminadas. Te recomiendo invertir un poco de tiempo en cada respuesta, elaborando con más detalle lo que se está respondiendo. La idea del sitio es apoyar respuestas con la mayor calidad posible